# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS with PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I use PHPmailer to send emails after you register your account after making them as a confirmation. However, after you create an account, I get this error: **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**.
I wonder what the problem is.
I did check similar problems like mine and tried the solutions given there but it didn't seem to work for me. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

//Include phpmailer files
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';

//name space defining
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

////Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

try {
//    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = '0991518@hr.nl';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = '0991518@hr.nl';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'Mamisayang1';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('0991518@hr.nl', 'Raisa.M.N');
    $mail->addAddress('0991518@hr.nl', 'Raisa.M.N');     //Add a recipient
//    $mail->addAddress('');               //Name is optional
    $mail->addReplyTo('0991518@hr.nl', 'Raisa.M.N');
    $mail->addCC('0991518@hr.nl', 'Raisa.M.N');
    $mail->addBCC('0991518@hr.nl', 'Raisa.M.N');

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);   //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Your account is created on our website!';
    $mail->Body    = '<b>Thank you for creating our account on our website! You have now full access to your account and to login!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'Thank you for creating our account on our website! You have now full access to your account and to login!';

    $mail->send();

    header('Location: confirmation.php');
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Email could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: `header('Location: confirmation.php');` - that's the only redirect I see here, so what does this `confirmation.php` script contain / do?

Comment: Yeah I checked the confirmation.PHP and found the problem. I did a require once in that file, causing too many redirects to happen back and forth. Erasing the require once fixed this problem.